# mySQL dump of individual tables in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to connect to a mySQL database and dump a series of tables stored in an array. When I run my code I get the errors below. Can anyone help me figure out what files it cannot find? Is it the table it cannot find or the destination folder on the local machine? Also how do I know / how can I check if I am connected to the database correctly?

```
Connection dbConn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    long companyId = 1002;
    String query = "select mobile_no, creation_dt from subscriber where company_id=?";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://"+ dbHost + ":" + dbPort + "/" + dbName + "?autoReconnect=true";

        System.out.println(dbUrl);

        dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUserId, dbPassword);
        stmt = dbConn.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setLong(1, companyId);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();


        System.out.println("STARTING DUMP");
        int i =0;
        dbTableName = dbTables.split(",");
        while(dbTableName[i] != null) {
            bPath = "\\" + dbHost + "." + dbTableName[i] + "." + new Timestamp(date.getTime()) + ".sql";
            System.out.println(bPath);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -u " + dbUserId + " -p " + dbPassword + " " + dbName + " " + dbTableName[i] + " --result-file=" + bPath);
            i++;
            //System.out.println(i);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception while reading info from database.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) rs.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception while closing result set!! - " + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception while closing statment!! - " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            if (dbConn != null) {
                dbConn.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception while closing db connection!! - " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Errors:

```
Exception while reading info from database.
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqldump": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at Backup.main(Backup.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
```

Comment: The error message says `The system cannot find the file specified`, so I'd try specifying the full path to `mysqldump`.

Comment: So I changed it to: `mysqldump -u root -p nielsoft lbs subscriber --result-file=C:/Users/Michael/Documents/SQL Backup/*******/subscriber.sql`
I still get the same errors though.

Comment: I meant the path to `mysqldump`, not the path to your file (though you may need to do that too). On my Win 7 machine with MySQL 5.5, the full path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\mysqldump.exe`. I'm not sure if you need the `.exe` extension but it can't hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem turned out to not be my code but a series of problems with permissions on the server. Took a while to figure out.